# Storing listbox item indices for persistent selection

Tags: vb.net, listbox, persistent-storage

I've had such fantastic help so far. I've got a listbox that automatically populates with the folder names of the path that the user browses to. When the browse button is clicked and the listbox populates the first folder is automatically selected:

```
ListBox1.SetSelected(0, True)
```

Next I wrote some code so that if the user tries to unselect the only folder, then it holds its selected state:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        My.Settings.Index1 = ListBox1.SelectedItem
    End If
    If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        ListBox1.SetSelected(My.Settings.Index1, True)
    End If
End Sub
```

However, ideally I need to hold the indices of all selected items in memory so that when the form reloads I can restore the selection along with the list box items. I think I would like to do this when the item count is greater than one. But I need some suggestions on how to do this. Not necessarily examples, but just the methodology or approach so I can make an attempt. Many thanks!!!

Comment: the listbox has a `SelectedIndices` property which would be all those selected, BUT if you are saving that assumes you will always be populating in the same order.  Especially with Files and Folders which the OS will serve up in no set order, it might be better to save the selected item (text/name).

Comment: @Plutonix - Brilliant. Selected items was the correct approach. I should have realised because I was using the same approach with just the items to populate the listbox with every item. I think I was thinking of it in the sense the adding selected items to the list of items, but of course you're adding those items to the list of items that will be shown as selected. Anyway, all made sense as you said it... Hope this comment makes sense ha!